# Is there a plugin in intellij that packages everything in a project and creates a shell script to launch the application?

Tags: java, deployment, intellij-idea

This seems like a straight forward plugin, I wonder if it already exists (yeah, I searched).  I have a project with some lib dependencies.

What I'm looking for does the following:

1. jars up classes built from your source code into one or more jars
2. gathers up the jar files your source depends on
3. creates a little shell script to set the classpath to the dependencies, and launches your main class.
4. zips all this up in a neat little package so you can take this zip/tar and deploy it, say on another machine.

Surely someone has written a simple deployer like this?   I can't find one in the plugins repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if IntelliJ has something like that, but Maven surely does what you need. You can use Maven (http://maven.apache.org/) with the Assembly plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). With some easy configuration you will get Maven to package a zip file for you with all the required JAR files in a subfolder. Then you can run the application with some script like the one below:

```
execute.cmd:
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -classpath "../lib/*" yourPackage.YourClassName
```

The script above assumes a pre-defined JAVA_HOME environment variable. There are other options such as WinRun4J to launch your application.

Maven is a pretty awesome tool - not only you can generate a ZIP file with everything from the command line, but you can also manage all your application dependencies, and it integrates nicely with a broad range of SCM tools to give you powerful tools, like the release plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) and others.

Comment: IntelliJ integrates very nicely with Maven. It is generally a good idea to separate your build process from the IDE you use to write and debug the code. You open a wide range of possibilities, such as having a dedicated build machine (with Hudson, for example). Maven will also run all your tests on every build to make sure everything is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Such tool was created several years ago and is called [BuildDesk](http://productiveme.com/download/). However, it was not very popular and the project was discontinued (no updates since 2009). I don't know if it's still compatible with the current IntelliJ IDEA version.

At the moment the solution is to use Maven, Ant or a combination of them with the built-in [Artifacts feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html). IDEA can already create an executable Jar with all the required dependencies, the only extra you need is a shell script or an executable wrapper like [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) or [Exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html). If you have a service, consider [JavaServiceWrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp).